# Unable to stop WildFly 8.2 service on Windows

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

Details

```
Windows 7 ultimate 32 bit
Java 7
Wildfly 8.2
```

I have installed WildFly as service successfully using below cmd

```
service.bat install /controller ip:9990 /user wildfly /password wildfly
```

But when I am trying to stop with below commands

```
service.bat stop /controller ip:9990 /user wildfly /password wildfly
service.bat stop
service.bat stop  /user wildfly /password wildfly
```

I have tried removing "CREDENTIALS" from service.bat as mentioned here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3149
and https://developer.jboss.org/thread/238135
even I have set JAVA_HOME in jboss-cli.bat.

But It is not working.

I keep getting below exception in **service.log**

```
[2015-07-04 13:50:12] [error] [  192] Failed to stop 'WildflyS' service
[2015-07-04 13:50:12] [error] [  192] The service cannot accept control messages at this time.
[2015-07-04 13:50:12] [info]  [  192] Stop service finished.
[2015-07-04 13:50:12] [error] [  192] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 6 (Failed to stop service)
[2015-07-04 13:50:12] [error] [  192] The service cannot accept control messages at this time.
```

**wildflys-stderr.log**

```
The service cannot accept control messages at this time.

Failed to stop servicewildflys-stderr.2015-07-04
```